# Why is my Super button minimizing whatever the active window is?

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, workspaces

I swear, it wasn't doing this when I first installed. I've searched all through the keyboard shortcut settings but didn't find anything relevant (the minimize window shortcut is set to Ctrl+Alt+0)

This annoying issue makes using Super+W and Super+S frustrating. Are there any other places where I could check to see why this is happening?

Comment: you mean Super minimizes any active window ? odd, I'd say this is a bug

Comment: Yes, that is exactly whats happening. So if I try to search by only pressing Super, or pressing Super+S will minimize any active window. Any ideas of things to delete/reinstall to get it working right again?

Comment: No ideas as of right now. Does this happen also if you manually click on the Ubuntu icon (with mouse )?

Comment: Also, i suggest you install `ccsm` (short for CompizConfig Settings Manager) and see if there's any settings enabled under Unity Plugin tab, and perhaps a few others (Expo, Desktop Wall).

Comment: The only thing I could find that seemed suspicious was: "Minimize Single Window Applications (Unsupported)", but that turned out to be unrelated.